# Extjs EntryForm.show is not a function

Tags: extjs, extjs5

My problem is, when i click on the Button, the following Error is displayed:

**TypeError: EntryForm.show is not a function**

Main.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.Main', {
  extend: 'Ext.container.Container',
  .....
  do Stuff
  .....
    tbar: [{
    text: 'Button',
    handler: function(){
      var mask = Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.EntryForm');
      mask.show(this);
```

EntryForm.js

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.main.EntryForm',{
  extend: 'Ext.Widget',
  ....
  generate my items for the form
  ....
```

When I use the EntryForm widget in the main.js class and use the create instead of the define and save it in a variable it works without problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not fully understand your question, but I think you need to add the EntryForm view to the Viewport before trying to show it, e.g.

```
var mask = Ext.create('MyApp.view.main.EntryForm');
Ext.Viewport.add(mask);
```

If EntryForm is set to hidden by default, then you would still need the

```
mask.show();
```

This link may also help http://training.figleaf.com/tutorials/senchacomplete/chapter2/lesson3/5.cfm